# React Native rendering works server side or client side?

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-native-ios, server-side-rendering

I have searched on many blog and documents for react native rendering process that React native work on server side rendering or client side rendering ?

If it work client side rendering with virtual DOM then why we need Node server and how it works with virtual DOM ?

Comment: The only thing that Node does with respect to RN is to run the JS packager for development